# How to simulate JME3 bullet physics as fast as possible

Tags: performance, physics, bullet, jmonkeyengine

I am working on a car simulation using bullet physics and I want to be able to speed up the simulation - even to be able to run the physics simulation as fast as possible.

I tried to call pSpace.update(1/60, 1) (which calls directly DynamicsWorld.stepSimulation), then listen for physicsTick and call this again ( => no waiting for anything). Unfortunately it looks like the thread is not waiting for all the bullet's work done and objects go through surface then (when I got over StackOverflowError).

I would probably need some mechansim to be called by bullet when the computation is done and I can call it again.

Or does bullet have its own clock which cannot be speeden up and I am completely wrong? I see the whole thing that it works as a single computation of forces on given time.

I know that JME3 can speed up bullet by calling stepSimulation(speed * tpf, 4), but it only speeds the simulation 4x on maximum as it makes 4 steps in a row, is this the way?

Thank you very much for anybody's hint.

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking to make the jBullet run faster (an optimization question), or run more often (try bulletAppState.setAccuracy(1/60) - but only works if the calculations are actually finished).